# unable to install mysql on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

I ran the following command

```
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.9-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

all goes well but when i hit

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

It gives me following errors

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mysql-server :
>   Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.7.20-1ubuntu16.04) but it is not
>   going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
>   broken packages.

To fix broken packages i did ran

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt-get update
```

but all in vain. Thanks to you guys in advance :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, I deleted MySQL with:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then I downloaded the .deb from [oficial page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) and used the following commands:

```
curl -OL https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config*
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server -y
```

At this point I had trouble because of Ubuntu eoan "incompability" (I'm using Ubuntu 19.10), displaying a message like: "The detected system (Debian jessie) is not supported by MySQL. If you believe the platform is compatible with one of the supported systems, one of the corresponding repositories may be selected". But I researched in [MySQL bugs page](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81474) and ran:

```
dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server -y
```

When it finishes, you may check the installation with:

```
sudo systemctl status mysql.service
```

And you should see something like...

[image: yep, my system is named Linus, you may laugh]

This worked for me, after trying solutions in StackExchange, none of which worked. I hope this helps! Looking for feedback if I did something wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to install mysql server with the version.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```